# Julia contrast coding

Tags: regression, julia, categorical-data

Having trouble assigning custom contrasts for categorical variables in regression. It looks like one can assign EffectsCoding or DummyCoding using `contrast` parameter

```
    model = fit!(lmm(@formula(response ~ 1 + factor + (1|sub)), data, 
             contrasts = Dict(:factor => EffectsCoding()) ))
```

but how to assign custom contrasts?

For instance, in R I can do

```
contrasts(data$factor) <- cbind("A_vs_B"= c(0.5, -0.5, 0), "AB_vs_C"= c(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5))

> contrasts(data$factor)
       A_vs_B   AB_vs_C
A        0.5     -0.25
B       -0.5     -0.25
C        0.0      0.50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to `EffectsCoding()`, DataFrames supports other contrast specifications. And in general, you can supply a contrast matrix (of the right size, *k-by-(k-1)* for *k* categories) as you do in R. An example:

```
using RDatasets        # install with Pkg.add("RDatasets")
using MixedModels      # install with Pkg.add("MixedModels")

iris = dataset("datasets", "iris")

contrast_matrix = [0.5 -0.25; -0.5 -0.25; 0.0 0.5]
fit!(lmm(@formula(SepalLength ~ 1 + Species + (1|PetalWidth)), iris, 
  contrasts = Dict(:Species => ContrastsCoding(contrast_matrix)) ))
```

The specific contrast matrix in the question is actually a Helmert coding matrix for a certain ordering of the categories. In this case, it is even simpler to do:

```
fit!(lmm(@formula(SepalLength ~ 1 + Species + (1|PetalWidth)), iris, 
  contrasts = Dict(:Species => HelmertCoding()) ))
```

`HelmertCoding` also takes optional arguments `base` and `levels` (not named, see docs) to switch around the category orderings.

Hope this helps, as the actual code gave a few problems on my v0.7 Julia, but on v0.5 it should work.

Comment: Thanks! This worked great for me! In R example, I could also assign names for each contrast. Is it possible with julia? at this point it just gives the names from the factor levels labels, but these are not correct (see the output of your iris example)

Comment: Also, function to get R datasets is "dataset", not "datasets" (i couldn't edit your post, as the system want at least 6 character edits)

Comment: @mike thanks. fixed the dataset. Sometimes cut-and-paste is better than retyping ;)

Comment: NP. Did you see my question about assigning names to contrasts like in R?

Comment: @mike I did. But since (as I mentioned), I did not actually get to successfully run the regression (because of v0.7 issue) the name problem is a bit fuzzy. Make a printout, possibly with a corresponding printout from R and ask another question. Maybe someone with 0.5 installed could answer.

Comment: I see. Thank you.